# Gradle build issue while running the command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp, google-dl-platform

We are trying to reidentifiation dataflow job by executing below command:-

```
gradle run -DmainClass=com.google.swarm.tokenization.DLPTextToBigQueryStreamingV2
-Pargs="
--region=${REGION}
--project=${PROJECT_ID}
--stagingLocation=gs://${DATAFLOW_TEMP_BUCKET}/staging
--tempLocation=gs://${DATAFLOW_TEMP_BUCKET}/temp
--maxNumWorkers=2
--runner=DataflowRunner
--tableRef=${PROJECT_ID}:deid_dataset.CCRecords_1564602825
--dataset=deid_dataset
--topic=projects{TOPIC_ID}
--autoscalingAlgorithm=THROUGHPUT_BASED
--workerMachineType=n1-standard-2
--deidentifyTemplateName=${REID_TEMPLATE_NAME}
--DLPMethod=REID
--keyRange=1024
--queryPath=gs://${DATA_STORAGE_BUCKET}/reid_query.sql"
```

Attaching the screenshot of error:-
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpzCW.jpg)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42NS9.jpg)